# App crashes on the device after Xcode updated to 4.6

Tags: xcode, deployment, ios-provisioning

I am trying to run my app on the device but it gives me the following error in the output window:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'**

This happened after the Xcode 4.6 update. I used to have Xcode 4.3.3 and it used to work normal on that one. My device is my iPad and the iOS installed on it is 5.1.1.

Is there any way to solve this without having to update my ipad to 6.1 because I'm afraid im gonna have to get provisioning license again because I think it wont recognize my iPad anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using *Auto Layout* in one or more of your NIBs, which is only supported in iOS 6+.

Remove it by unchecking *Use autolayout*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot trojanfoe! you saved my project. Really appreciated!!

Comment: Hi trojanfoe, The rotation doesnt work after I did this. Is this causing it not to rotate? Is there any way to make it rotate? because before when I had the iPad on portrait it had a different view and landscape a different one, but now when I rotate to landscape it still stays on the portrait view and it doesnt rotate.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this? BEcause if I turn the autolayout back on it doesnt work anymore. Please let me know

Comment: @Amin When you turn it off rotation doesn't work and when you turn it on again it also doesn't work?

Comment: When I uncheck "Use Autolayout" it does deploy on the iPad but it doesn't support rotation. And when I check "Use Autolayout" the whole project wont deploy on the iPad and it crashes.

Comment: @Amin Well autolayout alone won't provide rotation support; that's additional code you'll need to supply, which is now different for pre-iOS 6 and post-iOS 6.

Comment: But how come the rotation does work when I run it on the simulator?